# Android java activities

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have this two methods, and I what to put in pause this main activity when "something1*" happens and then change to someactivity1* while the main activity is paused. But my problem is that it doesn't change my activity, it freezes my main activity and it doesn't do anything else. It's probabli because I destroyed the thread but I can't see any solution and I'm not sure. (The method2 is inside a loop)
sorry for my english and thanks for the help

```
    public void method1(){

      super.onPause();
      run = false;
      while(){
        try{
          thread.join();
        }catch(InterruptedException e){
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }

      thread1 = null;

     Intent i = new Intent(someactivity1*);
     startActivity(i);

   }

   //the method2 is inside a loop
   public void method2(){

     if(something1*){

       onPause();

     }

   }
```

Comment: I cant figure out what your trying to do, but this code is all kinds of bad...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say `thread.join()`. This makes the main thread, aka the UI thread, wait for the Thread called `thread` to finish. In other words, you're locking your application with that.

Why do you want to manage pausing your app anyway? Android manages everything itself. Just start Activities, and don't call `onPause()` anywhere in your methods except for the `YourActivity.onPause()`.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely not be calling onPause.  This is a os callback method.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't you that put your activity in pause but the OS so you don't have to call onPause() method at all.

I think you should start simply the other actvity when "something" happens and the previous activity goes in pause.
Hope this help.